# Have make svn checkout and update various working copies

Tags: svn, version-control, makefile

I am trying to write a checkout-and-keep-updated makefile (generic or GNU) to operate on a number of svn working copies, say `repo_1` ... `repo_n`, like this

For all repos `i` do

- if `./repo_i` does not exist yet, `svn checkout repo_i` [it *should* actually be safe to assume that either none or all exist, but I tend to overengineer]
- else `cd ./repo_i && svn update`.

I am pretty sure that this should be elegantly doable with make, and it seems like a very straightforward thing to want, so someone else must have had that idea before me; still, I somehow could not find anything useful on SO and got stuck when building it myself.

The checkout part is ok, where I can do

```
DIRS = repo1 repo2 [...] repoN
all: $(DIRS)
$(DIRS):
    svn checkout http://some.svn.path/$@/trunk $@
```

but the update bit is trickier. I would like to prevent update from running after a fresh checkout (sure it won't hurt, but don't you just hate redundancy?), and then I am unsure how to "loop" over the repos without spelling out the update rule for every working copy and making it `.PHONY`, which then again might interfere with the checkout rule. My first idea looked like

```
DIRS = repo1 repo2 [...] repoN
update: $(DIRS)
    cd $(make-magic) && svn update
```

but this won't fly, because the rule to update `repo_i` will never be triggered if `./repo_i` already exists, and to check whether upstream is newer, I need to run `svn update` in `./repo_i`.

Has anyone else tried this before? Extra kudos if your idea coexists peacefully with `make -j`, just because! (also quite tedious in my case with N = 4).

PS: This is quite independent of the actual VCS, but it needs to work with svn (so any of those magic `git solve --all-problems` won't help here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first thing to remember is that for targets that have no prerequisites, they are considered to be up to date if the target exists.  So, if you have a rule with a target `repo1` with no prerequisites and that exists (either file or directory) on the filesystem, `make` believes that it's up-to-date and won't run the recipe.

The second thing to remember is that make deals only with filesystems and timestamps, by default.  There's no way to make a prerequisite relationship that depends on something else, like "is this SVN repository up to date?".

So.  The first thing you need to do is mark all your repositories as `.PHONY`, so that the recipes will always be run even if the directories exist.  Second, you need to change the recipe so that it *either* checks out the repository, if it doesn't exist, *or* updates it, if it does.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
DIRS = repo1 repo2 [...] repoN

.PHONY: update $(DIRS)
update: $(DIRS)
$(DIRS):
        if [ -d $@ ]; then \
            cd $@ && svn update; \
        else \
            svn checkout http://some.svn.path/$@/trunk $@; \
        fi
```

This also works with `-j`.  The above requires someone to explicitly `make update`.  If you want to embed it so that it always runs on every make (I don't like this myself...) you can put `update` as an order-only prerequisite on all the compile rules (pattern rules etc.).

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist, that works like a charm, also with `-j`, as you said. Would also +1 you, because I think your answer is clear and comprehensive, but lack rep :(